# You have an error in your SQL syntax when creating a procedure. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I get that error when I try to create a procedure. I dont know what's failing and I searched a lot if someone has the same error than me, but usually they mistake at delimiters, and I think i have them right.

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') 
SELECT SUM(robatori.quantitat_robada) FROM robatori WHERE param1=jugador_lla' at line 1 "

My query is the next:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE robatoris (IN param1 VARCHAR) 
SELECT SUM(robatori.quantitat_robada) FROM robatori WHERE param1=jugador_lladre;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks you all, that's my first question here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the length for input param on type `VARCHAR`.

Change it like the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE robatoris ( IN param1 VARCHAR(255) ) 
  SELECT SUM(robatori.quantitat_robada) 
    FROM robatori 
   WHERE param1=jugador_lladre;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

As you have only statement to execute, the `BEGIN` - `END` block was optional.
But it is advised to practice it in all cases.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE robatoris ( IN param1 VARCHAR(255) ) 
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(robatori.quantitat_robada) 
    FROM robatori 
   WHERE param1=jugador_lladre;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank u so much, what a dumb mistake xD. You answered really fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add BEGIN and END. Use TEXT type:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE robatoris (IN param1 TEXT)
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(robatori.quantitat_robada)
  FROM robatori
  WHERE param1=jugador_lladre;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```